# Why is "\n" a number "NaN" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, nan, control-characters

In JavaScript on Chrome and Firefox:

`isNaN( "\n" )` gives `false`
`parseFloat ( "\n" )` gives `NaN`

The same is yielded for `\t`, `\r` and `\f`.'

- `\n` is a number
- Parsed `\n` gives you Not A Number.
- Escaped characters such as the NULL byte `\0`, `\\` and `\"` do work as expected.
- We know that `NaN` is a number, just not representable by any other value
- So `\n` is a number, that's not representable.

Why do browsers implement it this way?

Comment: `parseFloat` might return `NaN`, but `+"\n"` returns `0`. There is a difference between *parsing* a string with `parse(Float|Int)` and simply converting it to a number. *"Why do browsers implement it this way?"* Because the specification dictates it.

Comment: I figured that there is a difference. I suspected parsing requires actual numbers ("NaN being can't display that as a number"), but I couldn't find googling NaN and parsing. @FelixKling could you link me that specification? I love to understand exactly why.

Comment: `parseFloat`: http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.3, `isNaN`: http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4 and `toNumber`: http://es5.github.io/#x9.3.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844

Comment: `typeof "\n" // "string"` .. `parseFloat("apples") // NaN` Are `apples` a number? What makes you say "`\n` is a number"?

Comment: `isNaN( "apples" ) // true`
`isNaN( "\n" ) //false`

See the accepted answer why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the `toNumber` conversion of any string that is comprised only of white space (or if it's empty) results in `0`.

```
console.log(Number("\n")); // 0
```

The `parseInt/Float` methods actually require *some* numeric content to be converted, though it'll allow leading spaces, and trailing garbage.

```
console.log(parseFloat("   123.45odsifjj")); // 123.45
```

---

The *toNumber* conversion is defined in [9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3.1).

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0

Comment: The documentation has a nice example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FisNaN of related strings that will produce false.

Comment: Thank you. This seems correct. I added the quote from the spec.

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the edit. Approved it as soon as I saw it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

<del>This is due to the dynamic typing when you call `isNaN`. `"\n"` is not a `NaN` (a value specified for `floats` and `doubles`), `"\n"` is a string.</del>

**EDIT:**
Apparently, when calling `isNaN("\n")`, `"\n"` is converted to a number first using `ToNumber` which does not have exact same behavior as `parseFloat`.

However, <del>W3C</del> w3schools says for [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp):

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat() returns NaN.

This is what causes the asymmetry.

Comment: `isNaN` converts the input to a number first though. See: http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4. So the reason for `isNan("\n")` is not that the input is a string. And w3schools is not affiliated with W3C in any way. Please don't make the mistake and mix them up.

Comment: @Derk-Jan: You should, they defined HTML, CSS, XML and lots of other standards. If you mean w3schools, I agree with you ;)

Comment: @FelixKling OFF COURSE haha. That's what I meant. I just copied W3C from his answer. I saw the website, recognized it and closed it.

Comment: @Derk-Jan: I guessed so, that's why the ";)" :)

Comment: Whoops... Seems I learned something here. Sorry for the mess.